# C# Linq Intersect

Tags: c#, linq, foreach, intersect

Most of the time I just use `foreach` statements, because that is a lot easier for me to code. 
Later on, when my code is done, I convert the `foreach` into LINQ statements where it makes sense.

I want to learn how to write good readable LINQ statements.
How would you guys convert this `foreach` code into a correct LINQ statement ?

```
private List<QARoles> GetUserRoles(User user)
{
    //TODO: Fix this with LINQ intersect.

    var result = new List<QARoles>();
    foreach (var role in user.Roles)
    {
        foreach (QARoles qarole in System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(QARoles)))
        {
            if (role.Name.Equals(qarole.ToString()))
            {                        
                result.Add(qarole);
            }                    
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Have you first tried to convert this to some linq?

Comment: I have used resharper, just like Malte R mentioned. But I do not like the outcome. I don't think it is nice to read.

Comment: As you can see looking at all these answers : the best answer was not generated by resharper. It takes great skills to write decent LINQ statements that are readable.

Comment: I completely agree :) and as a question this is a worthy one - my only point is that please when posing show what you have tried. We can help you from there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be simplified to:

```
var result = user.Roles
                 .Where(r => Enum.IsDefined(typeof(QARoles), r.Name))
                 .Select(r => (QARoles)Enum.Parse(typeof(QARoles), r.Name))
                 .ToList();
```

Comment: You return a list of User.Roles. It should be List<QARoles> ;-)

Comment: @Tony_KiloPapaMikeGolf yes, too much code today - fixed now. Still pretty readable hopefully.

Comment: You deserve the credits for best answer ! Alas, my reputation is less than 15. And someone gave -1 for my question, so I am even lower now.

Comment: You should still be able to accept that answer. Just saying... :P

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
var roles=System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(QARoles));
return roles.Where(r=>user.Roles.Any(role=>role.Name.Equals(r.ToString())).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return (from role in user.Roles 
        from QARoles qarole in System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(QARoles))
        where role.Name.Equals(qarole.ToString()) 
        select qarole)
.ToList();
```

or

```
 return user.Roles.SelectMany(role => System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(QARoles)).Cast<QARoles>(),
            (role, qarole) => new {role, qarole})
         .Where(t => t.role.Name.Equals(t.qarole.ToString())).Select(t => t.qarole).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

using ReSharper:

```
            return (from role in user.Roles
                from QARoles qarole 
                in System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(QARoles))
                where role.Name.Equals(qarole.ToString())
                select qarole)
                .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(QARoles)).Where(role => 
user.Roles.Any(r => r.Name == role.ToString()))
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this myself:

```
    return user.Roles
        .Select(r => r.Name).ToList<string>()
        .Select(str =>
        {
            QARoles qarole;
            bool success = System.Enum.TryParse(str, out qarole);
            return new { qarole, success };
        })
        .Where(pair => pair.success)
        .Select(pair => pair.qarole)
        .ToList();
```

But I dont think it has become better readable ;-)

Comment: Started writing a comment on how you could slightly improve on that - but realized it can be written in a much simpler way - check my answer.